# sqlite get index of specific row after sorting

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have an sqlite table called `scores` that has the columns `id` (PK) and `score`. Now I have an id and want to know at wich 'place' that person would be. A way to do that would be just `select * from scores order by score desc` and then look at the index of my id via code.

But I dont want to select the whole table if I just want to know the 'place' of an id so is it possible to get the place/index of a row after sorting it by score?

Comment: Have you looked at *row_number()* ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `RANK` here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY score DESC) rnk
    FROM scores
)

SELECT id, rnk
FROM cte
WHERE id = <some value>;
```

Note that if you don't expect any duplicates, then `ROW_NUMBER` could be swapped for `RANK` above.  If you do expect duplicates, then `DENSE_RANK` might also make sense instead of `RANK`.